# How to know atmospheric pressure on surface of another planet?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science

While reading this [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_atmosphere), the article says that, “The air pressure at Venus' surface is about 92 times that of the Earth.”

I’m familiar with the [barometric equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) and it’s derivation, however I realize that even if I “knew” the height of Venus’ atmosphere’s ‘edge’ at which point the pressure is essentially zero and density is essentially zero, how would I work the barometric equation down from said edge to get an reasonable estimate of the planet’s surface atmospheric pressure?

Comment: You need to have some idea of the mass of the atmosphere.

Comment: The pressure at the surface is the Newtons per square meter for the kilos of gas per square meter of the atmosphere to be supported time $g$ at the surface. A force balance tells you this.

Comment: Interesting comments, the barometric eqn does not require one to know the mass of gas that makes up the atmosphere (nor the mass per surface area of the planet). Would it be possible to develop an approximate solution to this question in generalized terms, e.g., if one knew radius of planet $r_p$, radius of atmosphere $r_a$, and total mass of atmosphere $M_a$?

Comment: @jakemcgregor Which version of the barometric formula are you using that doesn't explicitly depend on the molar mass of the atmosphere? That's the $M$ which is present in the wikipedia article you linked.

Comment: @J.Murray I’ll change my notation for total mass in my previous comment to $m_a$ (as that is what I understood Miller and Custer to be talking about); molecular mass is not the same as total mass, no? E.g, molecular mass of N2 gas is 28 kg/kg-mol, but the total N2 mass mass of earth’s atmosphere would not be 28 kg, no?

Comment: @jakemcgregor Perhaps I misread your question.  No, certainly not, the total mass of $N_2$ in the Earth's atmosphere is on the order of $10^{15}$ tons :)

Comment: @J.Murray OK, good deal. Any idea how to go about the problem?

Comment: If you know the reference pressure at a particular altitude, then you can just work backwards from the equation(s) in the wiki article - however, there is no "edge" at which the pressure is "essentially zero" because the pressure falls of exponentially.  Is that the kind of information you're starting with?

Comment: @J.Murray yes, how did “the guys at wiki” come up with Venus’ atm. press. at the surface? In my ignorance I thought maybe the prob. can be approached through what info ‘those guys’  could know without physically going to Venus’ surface, e.g., height to ‘edge’ of atm. (where $p$ is “zero”), mass/gravitation and surface radius of Venus, and atmospheric composition. However, they might have other info I haven’t mentioned and used some other way to calculate that ‘92 earths atmospheres surface pressure’. What would be min. info. req. to get est. of surf. press. from measurements made from earth?

Comment: I can't answer that, but my suspicion is that it is not possible to use only information obtained on Earth to get a reliable measure of another planet's surface pressure.  We know Venus' surface pressure because we [sent a lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_9#Lander) down through the atmosphere in 1975 and measured it.

Comment: @J.Murray thanks for sticking with me. I wonder what info Voyager 1 produced and how it was used to get an estimate of Titan’s surface pressure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Titan

Comment: Assuming the temperature was constant throughout the entire atmosphere, the ideal gas law tells you how many moles of gas occupy a certain volume and pressure. Perhaps you can integrate the exponential pressure equation times the volume to get a relation between initial pressure and moles (which can be converted to total mass)?